# angular js: several condition on a single attribute using NG-STYLE directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am into an awkward problem where I need to change the color of the text depending on the situation

here is what I am doing.

```
ng-style="{'color': 
order.order_status_id === '2' ? 'red' :
order.order_status_id === '3' ? 'green' : 
order.order_status_id === '5' ? 'blue' : 
''}"
```

The way I am using is kind of a workaround. Is there an actual `angular` solution for the scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you could do something like this, which is exactly the same but prettier.

In your controller define un object `color`:

```
$scope.color = {
  2: 'red',
  3: 'green',
  5: 'blue'
};
```

Then your ngStyle could be

```
ng-style="{'color': color[order.order_status_id]}"
```

That's all ;)